# onclick AJAX POST request(getting for some reason GET)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Good day.
I trying to send AJAX POST request when button is pushed.

this is the form and button button:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" >
                            <fieldset>

                            <!-- Form Name -->
                            <legend>Welcome!</legend>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="control-group">
                              <label class="control-label" for="Username">Username</label>
                              <div class="controls">
                                <input id="Username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="input-xlarge" >
                               ......
                               ......
<input type="submit" value="Register" id="register_button" name="register_button" class="btn btn-primary" >
```

I use bootstrap(if this is important.)
In my java script file(that included in html above) i have following:

```
$("#register_button").click(function() {

        var register_request = $.ajax({
            url: "/register",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'action' : 'register',

                .....
                ....
            }
            /*

            statusCode : {
                200: function(response){
                    ...
                },
                403: function(response){
                    ...
                }

            }
            */
        });


        register_request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            ...
        });

        register_request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            ...
        });
        return ;


    });
```

When i push submit button and my chrome Dev tools opened, i can see there only GET request.

Can someone explain why, and how i can make it POST request.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do the dev tools show a GET request for "/register" or some other file?  Do you have other code that's making a request?

Comment: it is in welcome.js - the name of file whereAJAX called written

Comment: `<form method="post">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return false in your click function.  Otherwise, the form (which defaults to GET) will still process.